# How to establish connection between server side socket in meteor and client side socket in html/javascript

Tags: javascript, sockets, meteor, socket.io

I have tried to implement like shown below, but two problems I am facing.

1. I cannot expose **io** Object to client that I get from npm socket.io-client library when its installed in meteor server and tried to access in client by adding a script tag shown below.

However, I solved it by fetching the io Object from cdnjs library.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.3/socket.io.js"></script>
```

2.Getting CORS error when trying to connect to server socket from client.
Client is not in meteor project, it is different app with only html and js file.

**client.js (file not in meteor) file has**

```
var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
```

**server.js (file in meteor) file has**

```
import socket_io from 'socket.io';
Meteor.startup(() => {
const server = http.createServer();
const io = socket_io(server);
});
```

Any leads would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the problem and made meteor socket connect to client(basic html, javascript). Implementation is as shown below.

**Meteor Server Side**

**Main.js**

```
import http from 'http';
import socket_io from 'socket.io';
var port = 3030;
const server = http.createServer();
server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);
const io = socket_io(server);

Meteor.startup(() => {
  socket_operation(io);
});

var socket_operation = Meteor.bindEnvironment((io) => {

    io.on('connection', Meteor.bindEnvironment((socket) => {
     .....
     your code goes here
     .....
    }
));

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  console.log('Socket server listening on ' + bind);
}
```

**Client Side**

**Main.js**

```
var socket = io('http://path/to/meteor/server:3030');
```

**index.html**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.3/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:3000/chatbox/main.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot expose io Object to client that I get from npm socket.io-client library when its installed in meteor server and tried to access in client by adding a script tag shown below.

Use the wrapper package instead: https://atmospherejs.com/joncursi/socket-io-client

> Getting CORS error when trying to connect to server socket from client.

Follow the instructions here to fix CORS errors: https://enable-cors.org/server_meteor.html

Answer (score 0):

**server/main.js**

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { WebApp } from 'meteor/webapp';
import io from 'socket.io';

const { httpServer } = WebApp;

Meteor.startup(() => {
   io(httpServer);
})
```

**client/main.html**

```
<body>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script>
    var socket = io();
    socket.on('connect', () => {
      console.log('connect')
    });
    socket.on('event', (data) => {
      console.log('event', data)
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
      console.log('disconnect')
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: client side doesn't have npm packages, it has just html and javascript. so the script tag you added wont be of help